# Data binding in Angular2 for loop

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm working on a project that pulls data from Firebase and displays it all inside of divs in a ngFor loop. When you click on a div, it opens a modal that displays the data in the div. Everything is working, except for when I click to open the modal, it displays the data for only the first div no matter which div I click on. I'm hoping that I am overlooking something simple to pass the correct data each time the div is clicked.

```
<div *ngFor="let game of games | async; trackBy:trackByGame" (click)="modal.open()">
  <gamemodal [game]="game"></gamemodal>
</div>
```

**component**

```
export class gameModalComponent {
  @Input() game: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  constructor() { }

  @ViewChild(ModalComponent) modal: ModalComponent;

  open() {
    this.modal.open();
  }

  close() {
    this.modal.close();
  }
}
```

**Here is where the games are loaded from Firebase**

```
  export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(gameModalComponent)
  modal: gameModalComponent;
  games: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  cwstring = '/Games/5';
  trackByGame(game: any){
   return game != null ? game.gameid: null;
  }

  constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.games = af.database.list(this.cwstring, {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'status'
      }
    })
  }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the controller.ts code

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski `export class gameModalComponent {
  @Input() game: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor() { }

  @ViewChild(ModalComponent)
  modal: ModalComponent;
  open() {
    this.modal.open();
  }

  close() {
    this.modal.close();
  }
}`

Comment: Please edit your answer with the code. Please also add the part where you assign the `games` variable with the actual data from Firebase.

Comment: try to make your service singleton by provides. you need to use your service and inject it as provide in compnent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution to this. I added a function in the component:

**app.component.ts**

```
  onClick(game) {
    this.modal.game = game;
    this.modal.open();
  }
```

Then modified the HTML:

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let game of games | async;trackBy:trackByGame" (click)="onClick(game)">
```

Seems to be working fine!

Answer (score 0):

> To customize the default tracking algorithm, NgFor supports trackBy option. trackBy takes a function which has two arguments: index and item. If trackBy is given, Angular tracks changes by the return value of the function.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

It looks like your trackBy function is incorrect, since the first parameter should be the index. Try changing  the function signature to

```
trackByGame(index: number, game: any){
   return game != null ? game.gameid: null;
}
```

and see if that helps.

Edit:

Also, `trackBy` is used for performance improvements and needed for large datasets only. If you are not tracking huge lists, I suggest doing it without the `trackyBy` on the `*ngFor` directive.

Comment: I added index to the function, but it doesn't seem to have any effect whether or not index is there.

Comment: The only reason trackBy is there, is because if you have a modal open and data updates from Firebase then the modal will close out. Adding trackBy allowed the modal to stay open.